# React on attribute change

Tags: reactjs

React component change when state change but can it change when attribute value changes.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var name="foo";
React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.body);
name="bar";
```

Above I would like to see 'Hello bar' rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any JavaScript platform that would take a **local** variable and automatically trigger an update of a UI component as you've shown (there's no practical and efficient way to monitor the variable for changes without using a timer).

While some JavaScript frameworks you may have encountered do change tracking on the properties of objects, ReactJS currently is not one of those.

In all React cases, you'll trigger the change by re-creating and rendering the component. But, as this is really just a virtual-DOM, it's not necessarily causing the DOM to be changed significantly (making it potentially more efficient).

In the simple case below, it would just mean that you call `render` again with the new value of `"bar"`.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var name="foo";
React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.body);
name = "bar";
React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.body);
```

In a more complex scenario, you might instead have a container component that is wired to changes from a Store and triggers the UI to be updated (again, by following a pattern like above, or you might find yourself needing to use [`forceUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) from within a container/component). You might choose to follow the Flux pattern ([more information](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html)).

Comment: Proxies can do this, but they're apparently only partly polyfill-able. Oh, also, guess which is the only browser that doesn't support proxies? ;)

Comment: @trysis-the `Proxy` object does not work with primitive data types, so it wouldn’t be an option in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I usually need to support IE. so I haven't experimented with Proxies. I guess you could always do dirty-checking, like angular 1, though there's a reason why they upgraded.

Comment: > there's no practical and efficient way to monitor the variable for changes without using a timer
Well, there is MutationObserver.  https://codepen.io/keldon/pen/YoEBxW

Answer (score 1):

React is designed with the assumption that component props may be treated as immutable (they don't change) once a component is rendered, and this will be enforced in future versions of React (as of React v0.13 this will trigger warnings), see here: [React V0.13 Changelog](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html#breaking-changes).

If you want to change the value of the property after render, you'll need to re-render the component with the new prop values.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will have to call forceUpdate on the React component.
which works to refresh.

```
c = React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.body);
c.forceUpdate();
```

However it's a sign of some kind of bad design. Ideally use setState to keep data in sync. Or pass the property from the parent component and call setState on the parent component.

Comment: What would a call to `forceUpdate` do? The value of name wouldn't have changed (as the property would have already been set).